# Using Mapperly Library for Custom Constructor Mapping C#

Tags: c#, constructor, mapping, mapperly

I am currently utilizing the Mapperly library and encountering an issue with generating a mapper. I am working with two classes, which are defined as follows:

```
class Class1
{
    public int Version { get; }
}
```

and

```
class Class2
{
    public Version Version { get; }
    
    Class2(Version version) {Version = version;}

}
```

The challenge arises with the Version class, which includes a constructor requiring two parameters:

```
public Version(int major, int minor)
```

With AutoMapeper I would go with

```
.ConstructUsing(x => new Version(x, 0))
```

However, it appears that Mapperly does not support this functionality, or I have yet to discover a solution. The documentation does not provide clarity for my specific situation. Could you please advise if it is possible to achieve the desired mapper generation with Mapperly, and if so, how I might go about it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a user-implemented mapping method which to map from an integer to a Version: [docs](https://mapperly.riok.app/docs/configuration/user-implemented-methods/).
Just add a method like the following to your mapper definition:

```
private Version MapMajorVersion(int majorVersion) => new Version(majorVersion, 0);
```